# Why does adding min/max properties change the width of a numeric HTML5 input element in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

HTML5 introduces input boxes for which only numeric values are valid.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="box 1" />
```

I noticed today that when specifying `min` and `max` attributes, the resultant width of the text box changes:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="box 2" min="0" max="100" />
```

These two elements are rendered differently in Chrome:

[image: textboxes of different widths]

This does not seem to happen in Firefox.

Test this yourself [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/eAPH8/).

Is this a bug, or is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with another box:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="box 3" min="0" max="100000000" />
```

You can see that chrome renders the boxes just a bit larger than they need to be to fit the highest possible number inside.

This seems to be a feature from chrome.